# syncing local development branch with remote branch

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2

How do people usually work with managing remote stuff with local stuff? Say I have an EC2 instance running ubuntu and my dev machine is an OS X. I have a symfony2 project in it. Do people usually work with files directly on the remote server on EC2? If yes how do they use a text editor such as sublime text on an EC2 box?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say how "people" work. But to me the best practice is following:

**Remote:**

- Install **mysql & php incl. all extensions** are needed. (symfony-project/web/config.php)
  You could use this tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.04-lucid-lynx-ispconfig-3
- Create **Database** for your project on server
- **Clone** your git repository on server and define **WebHook URLs**
- Create the file on your server. **`<?php git pull ?>`**

You'll never work on remote directly from now on! (except installing vendors by ssh)

**Local:**

- Install **local webserver**. I recommend http://php-osx.liip.ch/ But you can also use MAMP (don't like that).
- **Clone** git repository in web folder
- Define **remote Database** in symfony project
- **See changes local**

Commit&Push will pull remote automatically

Comment: Define remote database??? So you'll be developing in your local machine against your production database? Worst idea I ever heard.

Comment: I see no reason why to judge against my concept.
Symfony allows to use different databases in each environment. So while you're developing on --env=dev you'll use another db than on --env=prod which is your remote application.

doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname: %database_name%_test